# nth:child formula for alternating colour 2 column rows

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to style my boxes to have alternating background colours to an unknown "x" number of boxes.

I want them to style as follows, where A is white and B is grey.

A B

B A

A B

B A
... to x number of posts.

I've started with :nth-child(3n +1), but this fails on the 3rd row.
I am also aware of :nth-child(even) or :nth-child(odd)
Is this achievable?

Comment: your pattern repeat each 4 elements, so you need to consider 4n + a

Comment: ok I just tried :nth-child(4n), nth: child(4n+1). is there a way to define "a" to iterate in css?